# R: Find pattern matches of partial strings between two objects (case insensitive)

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have two dataframes that have fields that I need to match (i.e., tree species in this case) but are haphazardly written in different formats and naming schemes.

d1 is a species key with "common names" of species and a "species group" field; d2 is raw tree data with many trees (thus, species are repeated):

```
d1 <- data.frame(common.name = c("balsam fir", "white pine", "sugar maple", "red oak", 
"Lilac tree", "Chokecherry", "beark oak", "bigtooth aspen"), 
species.group = c("a","b","c","d","d","a","b","c"))

> d1  
common.name     species.group  
1  balsam fir        a  
2  white pine        b  
3  sugar maple       c  
4  red oak           d  
5  lilac tree        d  
6  chokecherry       a  
7  beark oak         b  
8  bigtooth aspen    c  



d2 <- data.frame(generic.name = c("Fir","Pine", "Oak", "Maple", "Elm", "Cherry", "Aspen", "Pine", "Pine", "Oak", "Fir", "Oak", "Pine", "Oak", "Oak", "Oak"))

> d2
   generic.name
1        Fir
2        Pine
3        Oak
4        Maple
5        Elm
6        Cherry
7        Aspen
8        Pine
9        Pine
10       Oak
11       Fir
12       Oak
13       Pine
14       Oak
15       Oak
16       Oak
```

I need to group the tree species d2$generic.name by the corresponding d1$species.group by pattern matching d1$common.name and d2$generic.name:

```
key.names <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(d1$common.name, " ", fixed=TRUE))))
key.groups <- unique(tolower(d1$species.group))

d2$species.group <- function(matching)?

> d2
       generic.name    species.group
1           Fir             a
2          Pine             b
3           Oak             c
4         Maple             d
5           Elm             d
6        Cherry             c
7         Aspen             d
8          Pine             b
9          Pine             b
10          Oak             c
11          Fir             a
12          Oak             c
13         Pine             b
14          Oak             c
15          Oak             c
16          Oak             c
```

Sorry for incomplete code example, but I'm quite stuck on what the function would look like. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it did not work for you and what the expected results are. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for the advice pcantalupo; I'll provide more complete and verifiable example code next time. @jlhoward thanks for the empathy, this newb appreciates it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
d1 <- c("balsam fir", "white pine", "sugar maple", "red oak", "lilac tree")
d2 <- c("Fir","Pine", "Oak", "Maple", "Japanese Lilac")

words <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(d2, " ", fixed=TRUE)))
words
# [1] "fir"      "pine"     "oak"      "maple"    "japanese" "lilac"   

get.category <- function(x)names(which(sapply(words,grepl,x,fixed=TRUE)))
data.frame(name=d1,
           category=sapply(d1, get.category),
           row.names=seq_along(d1))
#          name category
# 1  balsam fir      fir
# 2  white pine     pine
# 3 sugar maple    maple
# 4     red oak      oak
# 5  lilac tree    lilac
```

Comment: Thanks jlhoward! As I described it initially I think your solution works great, but unfortunately I think i did not describe my data structure adequately. I have updated the post to clarify. I am trying to adapt your solution now but still not there.

Comment: Your new data set doesn't make sense to me. For instance, row 3 of `d2` is `"Oak"`. But that could correspond to `"red oak"` (group d), or `"beark oak"` (group b). Which is it?